# Heroku rejects my git push request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

So I created a Rails 4 app and was able to push it upstream to Heroku properly the first time. Every since then I haven't been regularly pushing my changes. I just got to a very significant checkpoint and decided to try to push my changes to the actual site on heroku but it rejects my request saying that it failed to compile my Ruby app. I've copy and pasted some of the feedback my command line provided me with in hopes that someone has had a similar error and can give me some ideas as to what might be wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token name «users», expected punc «,» (line: 11341, col: 35, pos: 318042)
       Error
       at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20140625-619-93tzcv.js:2357:10754)
       at js_error (/tmp/execjs20140625-619-93tzcv.js:2357:10973)
       at croak (/tmp/execjs20140625-619-93tzcv.js:2357:19198)
       at token_error (/tmp/execjs20140625-619-93tzcv.js:2357:19335)
       at expect_token (/tmp/execjs20140625-619-93tzcv.js:2357:19558)
       at expect (/tmp/execjs20140625-619-93tzcv.js:2357:19696)
       at expr_list (/tmp/execjs20140625-619-93tzcv.js:2357:27763)
       at /tmp/execjs20140625-619-93tzcv.js:2357:29817
       at /tmp/execjs20140625-619-93tzcv.js:2357:27576
       at /tmp/execjs20140625-619-93tzcv.js:2357:30108


Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:picritique.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:picritique.git'
```

Answer (score 3):

A similar error occurred to me recently when deploying a rails 4 app on heroku, and what I did was to precompile the assets in my local machine and then send them to heroku.

Try to do in your local:

```
rake assets:precompile
git add .
git commit -m 'assets precompiled locally'
git push heroku master
```

And it worked.  I haven't figured the reason yet to do this, so any insight on this will be appreciated.  It just worked for me in this way.

Comment: This actually worked. I forgot about this trick. Thanks a lot Hernan.

Comment: Lots of posts says `rake assets:precompile` but not mention to `git add` So that's what's missing!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like maybe you've got an error in your JavaScript.  Are you able to run `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace` locally?

Comment: I forgot to precompile, but it's working now. Thanks for taking time out to help though.

Comment: My error, is a bower mal-formed installation, removing it works very well!

Answer (score 0):

I was making mistake in code as below

`_companyService.get({companyId },function(result) {...`

Fixed it as
`_companyService.get({ companyId: companyId },function(result) {...`